# Bash command route malfunction

Tags: bash, shell, coffeescript

Given this (among more...):

```
compile_coffee() {
    echo "Compile COFFEESCRIPT files..."
    i=0
    for folder in ${COFFEE_FOLDER[*]}
    do
        for file in $folder/*.coffee
        do
            file_name=$(echo "$file" | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' | awk -F "." '{print $1}')
            file_destination_path=${COFFEE_DESTINATION_FOLDER[${i}]}
            file_destination="$file_destination_path/$file_name.js"
            if [ -f $file_path ]; then
                echo "+ $file -> $file_destination"
                $COFFEE_CMD $COFFEE_PARAMS $file > $file_destination #FAIL
                #$COFFEE_CMD $COFFEE_PARAMS $file > testfile
            fi
        done
        i=$i+1
    done
    echo "done!"
    compress_javascript
}
```

And just to clarify, everything except the #FAIL line works flawessly, if I'm doing something wrong just tell me, the problem I have is:

- the line executes and does what it have to do, but dont write the file that I put in "file_destination".
- if a delete a folder in that route (it's relative to this script, see below), bash throws and error saying that the folder do not exist.
- If I make the folder again, no errors, but no file either.
- If I change the $file_destination to "testfile", it create the file with correct contents.
- The $file_destination path its ok -as you can see, my script echoes it-
- if I echo the entire line, copy the exact command with params and execute it onto a shell in the same directory the script is, it
  works.

I don't know what is wrong with this, been wondering for two hours...

Script output (real paths):

```
(alpha)[pyron@vps herobrine]$ ./deploy.sh compile && ls -l database/static/js/
===============================
=== Compile ===
Compile COFFEESCRIPT files...
+ ./database/static/coffee/test.coffee -> ./database/static/js/test.js  
done!
Linking static files to django staticfiles folder... done!
total 0
```

Complete command:

```
coffee --compile --print ./database/static/coffee/test.coffee > ./database/static/js/test.js
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT** I've made some progression through this.
In the shell, If I deactivate the python virtualenv the script works, but If I call deactivate from the script it says command not found.

Comment: Does `./database/static/js` exist before you run the script?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming destination files have no characters as spaces in their names, directories exist etc. I'd try adding 2>&1 e.g.

```
$COFFEE_CMD $COFFEE_PARAMS $file > testfile 2>&1
```

compilers may put desired output and/or compilation messages on stderr instead of stdout. You may also want to put full path to coffee , e.g. /usr/bin/coffee instead of just compiler name.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the problem wasn't the bash script itself. A few lines later the deploy script perform the collectstatic method from django. Noticed that until that line the files were there, I started reading that the collecstatic have a cache system. A very weird one IMO, since I have to delete all the static files and start from scratch to have the script working.

So... the problem wasn't the bash script but the django cache system. Im not givin' reputation to me anyways.

The full deploy script is here: https://github.com/pyronhell/deploy-script-boilerplate and everyone is welcome if you can improve it.

Cheers.